# Problem with aldryn_form after update Django and Django CMS

Tags: django, django-forms, django-cms

I'm trying to update my requirements.txt I got `Django=1.11.29, DjangoCMS=3.7.4, aldryn-forms=5.0.4` and try to update to => `Django=3.2, DjangoCSM=3.9.0, aldryn-forms=6.2.1`.
But when I upgrade packages, `./manage.py migrate` and do `./manage.py cms list plugins` the `FormPlugin` is no more installed.

Here my origin requirements.txt :

```
aldryn-apphooks-config==0.6.0
aldryn-boilerplates==0.8.0
aldryn-categories==1.2.0
aldryn-common==1.0.5
aldryn-forms==5.0.4
aldryn-translation-tools==0.3.0
asgiref==3.3.4
backports.csv==1.0.7
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
bleach==3.1.5
cachetools==4.1.1
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
cmsplugin-svg==0.1.2
cssselect==1.1.0
cssutils==1.0.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==1.11.29
django-absolute==0.3
django-admin-sortable2==0.7.7
django-appconf==1.0.4
django-appdata==0.3.0
django-bootstrap3==14.1.0
django-ckeditor==5.9.0
django-classy-tags==1.0.0
django-cms==3.7.4
django-cms-tools==0.7.1
django-emailit==0.2.4
django-filer==1.7.1
django-formtools==2.2
django-js-asset==1.2.2
django-macros==0.4.0
django-mptt==0.11.0
django-multiupload==0.5.2
django-parler==2.1
django-polymorphic==2.1.2
django-ranged-response==0.2.0
django-sekizai==1.1.0
django-simple-captcha==0.5.14
django-sizefield==1.0.0
django-sortedm2m==3.0.2
django-standard-form==1.1.1
django-tablib==3.2
django-tools==0.46.1
django-treebeard==4.3.1
djangocms-admin-style==1.5.0
djangocms-attributes-field==1.2.0
djangocms-column==1.11.0
djangocms-file==2.4.0
djangocms-googlemap==1.4.0
djangocms-installer==1.2.3
djangocms-link==2.6.1
djangocms-local-navigation==1.4.1
djangocms-picture==2.4.0
djangocms-slider==0.2.5
djangocms-snippet==2.3.0
djangocms-style==2.3.0
djangocms-text-ckeditor==3.10.0
djangocms-video==2.3.0
easy-thumbnails==2.7
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
html5lib==1.1
icdiff==1.9.1
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==1.7.0
jdcal==1.4.1
jsmin==2.2.2
lxml==4.5.2
odfpy==1.4.1
openpyxl==3.0.5
packaging==20.4
Pillow==7.2.0
pprintpp==0.4.0
premailer==3.7.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-slugify==4.0.1
pytz==2020.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.24.0
six==1.15.0
sorl-thumbnail==12.6.3
soupsieve==2.0.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
tablib==2.0.0
text-unidecode==1.3
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
tzlocal==2.1
Unidecode==1.1.1
urllib3==1.25.10
webencodings==0.5.1
xlrd==1.2.0
xlwt==1.3.0
YURL==1.0.0
zipp==3.4.1
```

Here my requirements.txt after upgrade :

```
aldryn-apphooks-config==0.6.0
aldryn-boilerplates==0.8.0
aldryn-categories==1.2.0
aldryn-common==1.0.5
aldryn-forms==6.2.1
aldryn-translation-tools==0.3.0
asgiref==3.4.1
backports.csv==1.0.7
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
bleach==4.0.0
cachetools==4.2.2
certifi==2021.5.30
chardet==4.0.0
cmsplugin-svg==0.1.2
cssselect==1.1.0
cssutils==2.3.0
defusedxml==0.7.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.6
django-absolute==0.3
django-admin-sortable2==1.0
django-appconf==1.0.4
django-appdata==0.3.2
django-bootstrap3==15.0.0
django-ckeditor==6.1.0
django-classy-tags==2.0.0
django-cms==3.9.0
django-cms-tools==0.7.1
django-emailit==0.2.4
django-filer==2.0.2
django-formtools==2.3
django-js-asset==1.2.2
django-macros==0.4.0
django-mptt==0.12.0
django-multiupload==0.5.2
django-parler==2.2
django-polymorphic==3.0.0
django-ranged-response==0.2.0
django-sekizai==2.0.0
django-simple-captcha==0.5.14
django-sizefield==1.0.0
django-sortedm2m==3.0.2
django-standard-form==1.1.1
django-tablib==3.2
django-tools==0.48.3
django-treebeard==4.5.1
djangocms-admin-style==2.0.2
djangocms-attributes-field==2.0.0
djangocms-column==1.11.0
djangocms-file==3.0.0
djangocms-googlemap==2.0.0
djangocms-installer==2.0.0
djangocms-link==3.0.0
djangocms-local-navigation==1.4.1
djangocms-picture==3.0.0
djangocms-slider==0.2.5
djangocms-snippet==3.0.0
djangocms-style==3.0.0
djangocms-text-ckeditor==4.0.0
djangocms-video==3.0.0
easy-thumbnails==2.7.1
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
html5lib==1.1
icdiff==2.0.4
idna==3.2
importlib-metadata==4.6.3
jdcal==1.4.1
jsmin==2.2.2
lxml==4.6.3
odfpy==1.4.1
openpyxl==3.0.7
packaging==21.0
Pillow==8.3.1
pprintpp==0.4.0
premailer==3.10.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-slugify==5.0.2
pytz==2021.1
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.26.0
six==1.16.0
sorl-thumbnail==12.7.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
tablib==3.0.0
text-unidecode==1.3
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
tzlocal==2.1
Unidecode==1.2.0
urllib3==1.26.6
webencodings==0.5.1
xlrd==2.0.1
xlwt==1.3.0
YURL==1.0.0
zipp==3.5.0
```

Here capture of the `./manage.py cms list plugins` after upgrade :

[image]

Comment: And is `aldryn_forms` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Hey @markwalker_ thanks for your answer yes aldryn_forms is in my INSTALLED_APPS. I've update to Django===2.2 and the FormPlugin is still installed but when I update Django=3 the FormPlugin is no longer installed

Comment: Ah I see. Looking at the repo for it, it's not tested against django 3 so perhaps it doesn't work with it yet.